# Does MS Access suppress primary key violations on Inserts?

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key

I am in the process of re-writing an MS Access database to SQL server and have found an strange issue in Access that I am hoping someone can help with.

I have a table let's call it 'Main' with a Primary Key on the Account that is indexed and doesn't allow for duplicates. Seems simple enough but my issue is occurring when data is getting Inserted.

My INSERT query is (the number of fields have been limited for brevity)

```
INSERT INTO Main (Account, SentDate, Amount)
SELECT C.Account, C.SentDate, C.Amount
FROM 
    (CALLS C LEFT JOIN Bals B ON C.Account = B.ACCT_ID) 
LEFT JOIN AggAnt A ON C.Account = A.Account
```

The issue is this, if I run the `SELECT` portion of my query I get 2365 records but when I run the `INSERT` I get 2364 records.  So I did some checking and I found one Account is duplicated the difference between the records is the SentDate and the Amount.  But Access is inserting only one of the records and not throwing any kind of error message or anything.  There is nothing in the query that says select the most recent date, etc.

Sample Data:

```
Account    SentDate   Amount
12345678   8/1/2011   123.00
23456789   8/1/2011   45678.00
34567890   8/1/2011   7850.00
45678912   8/1/2011   635.00
45678912   5/1/2011   982.00
56789123   8/1/2011   2639.00
```

In the sample I have one account that is duplicated 45678912 when I run my INSERT, I get no errors and I get the record from 8/1/2011.

Why is Access not throwing an error when this violates the PK on the table?  Is there some quirk in Access to select one record and just skip the other?

I am totally stumped by this issue so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After HansUp pointing me in the direction of checking for SetWarnings = false.  I found it buried in my code which is why there was no warning message about the records not being inserted due to primary key violations.

A word of caution would be to make sure you want these messages suppressed.

Comment: The only reliable way to execute SQL in Access is with `.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError`. DoCmd.OpenQuery and DoCmd.RunSQL are both something that should be avoided because when you turn SetWarnings OFF, you have no idea what errors are being hidden from you. I have written a function, SQLRun(), as a replacement for DoCmd.RunSQL that I've posted many times. It is just a wrapper around `.Execute, strSQL, dbFailOnError` so you don't have to write the error handler every time. Search for it on SO and try it out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards your function. I'll take a look for future use.  My current app is being rewritten and I am not going to make any code changes to an already very unstable application.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "The only reliable way to execute SQL in Access..." ...when using DAO.

Answer (score 5):

How are you running the query?  If you're using `DoCmd.RunSQL`, switch to using the `.Execute` method of a DAO database object, and use `dbFailOnError`.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "your insert statement"
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

**Edit**: If Main is an ODBC link to a SQL Server table, I would examine the [Errors Collection (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834805.aspx) after `db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError`

Comment: I currently run my query using DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryname", acViewNormal, acEdit and get no errors but it is also run the query by double-clicking on it I still get no errors and it runs successfully.

Comment: Which number does it display when asking you for confirmation?

Comment: It doesn't display anything that is the strange part.

Comment: If you don't get the confirmation dialog, "You are about to append 2365 row(s)."  that makes me wonder whether SetWarnings is False.  Do you have that anywhere in your application, and perhaps it didn't get set back to True?

Comment: The SetWarnings is set to True, I just ran some code to set it back in the event it was on False.  Still no message when I run the query.

Comment: Access has an option to suppress/enable confirmations for Action queries.  Do you have that disabled?  (I'm grasping at straws.)  In A2007, it's on the Advanced section of the Access Options window, after you first click on the Office button.  It was easier to find that setting in A2003, but can't remember where just now.

Comment: It is disabled but I do get the message on some queries and not others.  I really don't know what is going on either, totally stumped.  with this one.

Comment: Thanks for somewhat pointing me in the right direction the process that runs the query from VBA has a SetWarnings to False. This is why we never get the message and it inserts the incorrect number of records.  So now it is back to the business to determine what they want.

Comment: SetWarnings strikes again!  We should highlight that point as a warning to others.  You could submit the resolution as an answer and accept that one instead of mine.  That would be great because I **despise** SetWarnings False!

Comment: I posted the resolution as the answer. It won't let me accept it until tomorrow, darn SetWarnings for causing so many problems. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.  And thanks for posting that answer.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some quirk in Access to [update] one record and just skip the
>   other?

Yes, you can control this behaviour at the engine level (also at the recordset level if using OLE DB).

For OLE DB (e.g. ADO) the setting is [`Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa140022):

> determines the behavior of the Jet database engine when SQL DML bulk
>   operations fail. When set to allow partial completion of bulk
>   operations, inconsistent changes can occur because operations on some
>   records could succeed and others could fail. When set to allow no
>   partial completion of bulk operations, all changes are rolled back if
>   a single error occurs. The **Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops**
>   property setting can be overridden on a per-**Recordset** basis by
>   setting the **Jet OLEDB:Partial Bulk Ops** property in the
>   **Properties** collection of a **Recordset** object.

Note the default is to allow no partial completion of bulk operations.

Comment: But that's the default behavior of Jet when not specifically telling Access to IGNORE errors (which is what you're doing when you use OpenQuery or RunSQL with SetWarnings turned OFF).