# MSAccess VBA code not working on second run

Tags: ms-access, vba

The below code is bound to a button. For some reason the below code executes correctly the first time. On the second time, for some users, it does not populate the fields on the website. What could the issue be?

```
Me!WebBrowser0.Navigate "http://bk00app0001/PMD Image Upload/"

While Me.WebBrowser0.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementById("MainContent_Year").Value = Forms![Main Menu]![SeasonList].Value
Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementById("MainContent_ItemNumber").Value = Me.OpenArgs
Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementById("MainContent_btnLock").Click
```

I believe I need to set Me!WebBrowser0 = Nothing on the Close event.
However, Me!WebBrowser0 = Nothing throws an error. Any ideas as to how to do this?

UPDATE

On the second time this code is called MS Access throws the following error when it hits this line:

```
Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementById("MainContent_Year").Value = Forms![Main Menu]![SeasonList].Value

'Object variable or With block variable not set'
```

Looks like it was a timing issue. I was able to solve it by adding the following code before I set any of the values on the webpage:

```
While Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementsByTagName("p").Length < 10
     DoEvents
Wend
```

I am now getting the error: "Runtime error '430' class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface"

This error refers to the following line of code:

```
Set Cnxn = New ADODB.Connection
```

Here is a screenshot for the line of code above:
http://postimage.org/image/2v7p8diis/

The above code is called when I close the form that has the button that calls the browser code.

Comment: Is it throwing any errors or simply not responding? Do you have it in a On Error Resume Next catch that's hiding error messages?

Comment: I'll add an Error Handler and see if it's throwing errors. It shouldn't be throwing errors because it works for some users and not others. For the users that it doesnt work for it seems none of the getElementById code has been executed.... i'll have to debug and check if the value is blank. I'll post tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @HansUp Could it be a timing issue?

Comment: @HansUp I'm now getting a different error...

Comment: @HansUp Is SetWarnings False bad?

Comment: Worse than bad, IMO.  See here for one example of the confusion which can be caused when you SetWarnings off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115247/does-ms-access-suppress-primary-key-violations-on-inserts  You could also search Stack Overflow for Fenton and SetWarnings for more arguments against it.  But, even if you're meticulous about ensuring SetWarnings always gets turned back on appropriately, it's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
While Me!WebBrowser0.Document.getElementsByTagName("p").Length < 10
 DoEvents
Wend
```

Solved the first issue.

The second issue was due to referencing a non-existent DLL on the user's machine.