# Why do some VBA errors not trigger error handling?

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

Whilst updating my code this morning, I caused an error - I replaced a function with a string but forgot to take out the parenthesese that followed, which caused the code not to run.

However, this didn't trigger my error handling code, so it didn't report the error and it took me ages to find it by stepping through the code.

Code below:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Update to say the user is no longer logged in

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Last Logged Out"

'Backup data
If (strNameChecker <> "workshop.accdb") Then

        strBackupUser = Nz(GetFullName(), "default")
        strFriendlyNow = Replace(Now(), "/", "-")
        strFriendlyNow = Replace(strFriendlyNow, ":", "-")
        strNewFileName = "F:\Data\Central\Marketing\Databases\Prospects Database\Auto-Backups\TargetDBData - backed up by " & strBackupUser() & " on " & strFriendlyNow & ".mdb"
        BackupProspects "F:\Data\Central\Marketing\Databases\Prospects Database\TargetDBData.mdb", "" & strNewFileName & ""
        sSql = "INSERT INTO [Backup to Delete] ([Version Number]) SELECT '" & strNewFileName & "' AS Expr1;"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sSql


'Delete the temporary version of the front end.
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update - Version Shutdown"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Application.FollowHyperlink "F:\Data\Central\Marketing\Databases\Prospects Database\Prospects Database Shutdown.accdb"

End If

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "The database has generated an error. Please contact the database administrator, quoting the following error message: '" & Err.Description & "'", vbCritical, "Database Error"

End Sub
```

The error is caused by the two parenthese after strBackupUser about halfway down the code - delete these and the code works fine - but why doesn't this error trigger the error handling?

Comment: I use On Error Goto ErrHandler for the Error Handling btw, first line of the subroutine.

Comment: @JMK - Posted - the version I've posted is the one that causes the error, take out the parenthese following strBackupUser to make it work.

Comment: @HansUp Never turn off warnings? That's not really practical. I don't really want my users to have to OK every time I run a query that adds or deletes. Sometimes you have to turn warnings off for a seamless user experience.

Comment: @OliJeffery You won't get those prompts with `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `RunSQL` and `OpenQuery` for action queries.

Comment: Hi @HansUp - nonetheless, I think that comes down to preferences in coding style, as do all your other comments, none of which are causing the error or stopping the error code from working. Thanks though.

Comment: Fine.  I deleted them all except for SetWarnings.  Before you dismiss that as only a matter of style, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115247/does-ms-access-suppress-primary-key-violations-on-inserts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't appear to have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. As a result, all the string variables will be silently declared as `Variant`. I'm not sure what the compiler will make of the expression `strBackupUser()`, I guess it will attempt some kind of horrible late-bound object or array access.

I suggest that you add `Option Explicit` first, then explicitly declare all your variables as strings, then see whether you get a compiler error.

Here is a useful ["war story"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/developingfordynamicsgp/archive/2009/08/07/what-does-option-explicit-do-in-vba.aspx) that illustrates how and why to use it.