# Access VBA - detect duplicated records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a VBA procedure (behind a form) which does the following ;-

- imports data from an XML file into am empty temporary table (with one key field called ID)
- creates a spreadsheet based on a query from the temp table
- appends the data into a backup table via an append query (backup table has same table format as the temp table, i.e. a key field called ID)
- deletes all from the temp ready for the next run

After the import of the data from XML, I want to be able to capture scenarios where the same file is trying to be imported twice (i.e. where the temp table contains IDs which also exist in the backup table), tell the user via msgbox, and then quit the Sub.

I would have thought it'd be possible to do it by error code handling when trying to append, capturing the error about duplicate keys.

I have an append query to append to the backup, and if I run this query via the Query itself, I get warnings etc. about there being duplicates, with option to continue to run the query or not.

However, I am doing this in VBA via OpenQuery (and have turned warnings off), and so nothing happens? I can't seem to capture an error code.

I tried writing a select query to identify any duplicate IDs, and then somehow detect if that query returned any rows, but also can't get this to work as cannot find a way to detect if the query returns any rows or not.

Comment: I'm unclear about how the spreadsheet fits into this.  Do you still want the spreadsheet created if the temp table includes rows which are duplicated in the backup table?

Comment: No. It should detect this, and give a clear message to user that duplicates present and to check the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I am doing this in VBA via OpenQuery (and have turned warnings off), and so nothing happens? I can't seem to capture an error code."*

Turning `SetWarnings` off suppresses information in general, so that is why your expected error message doesn't appear.  Many experienced Access developers advise turning `SetWarnings` off is a bad idea.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7115247/77335) for another example of how frustrating troubleshooting can be with `SetWarnings` off.

Since you have an "append query", execute it with the `DAO.Database .Execute` method instead of using `OpenQuery`.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO backup_table(ID, fld1, fld2)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT ID, fld1, fld2 FROM temp_table"
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

With `SetWarnings` on (`True`) that approach will trigger an error message due to key violations when the backup table already includes `ID` values you're trying to add.

Separately, if you want a count of the duplicates, this query should give you that.

```vb
SELECT Count(*) AS count_of_duplicates
FROM
    temp_table AS t
    INNER JOIN backup_table AS b
    ON t.ID = b.ID
```

If you want to insert non-duplicate `temp_table` rows into `backup_table`, try a query like this ...

```vb
INSERT INTO backup_table(ID, fld1, fld2)
SELECT t.ID, t.fld1, t.fld2
FROM
    temp_table AS t
    LEFT JOIN backup_table AS b
    ON t.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID Is Null
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used your DAO.Database .Execute method and now it gives an "error 3022" dialog about duplicate keys and stops the process (which is what I wanted). This is fine, but I want a nicer easier error text for the user. How can I change the error text?

Comment: You could add an error handler to your VBA procedure to trap error 3022 and display your custom message to the user.  However based on your response about the spreadsheet, perhaps you should first count the duplicates.  If `count_of_duplicates` = 0, write the spreadsheet and append the temp table rows to the backup table.  If `count_of_duplicates` > 0, notify user.

Comment: OK, but how can I detect in VBA the value of count_of_duplicates in an VBA if statement? This is a field as returned by a query...

Comment: Save the query as `qryDuplicates`, then in VBA use `If DLookup("count_of_duplicates", "qryDuplicates") > 0 Then ...`